# Return all rows where one field is the same, but there is at least one difference in the other fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query that will return records where the field in column 1 is the same, but there is at least one difference in specific other columns.

For example:
I want to compare columns 2 and 4 for each value in column 1.  If there is a difference, I need all fields in both rows to return.

This data set
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5
Air Filter|Shape|Round|Color|Red
Air Filter|Shape|Panel
Nerf Bar|Finish|Polished|Material|Stainless Steel
Nerf Bar|Finish|Powder Coated|Material|Stainless Steel
Hood|Color|Black|Finish|Powder Coated
Hood|Finish|Powder Coated|Color|Black

would return:
Air Filter|Shape|Round|Color|Red
Air Filter|Shape|Panel|NULL|NULL
because the value in column 4 does not match between the records
And
Hood|Color|Black|Finish|Powder Coated
Hood|Finish|Powder Coated|Color|Black
because the values in column 2 and column 4 do not match between the records

I can only get one record for each part to return.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
Select *
from [My_Table] as a 
where exists(select null from [My_Table] as b
where a.column1 = b.column1
and (a.column2 = b.column2
or a.column3 = b.column3
or a.column4 = b.column4
or a.column5 = b.column5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.column1, t1.column2, t1.column3, t1.column4, t1.column5
    FROM My_Table t1
        INNER JOIN My_Table t2
            ON t1.column1 = t2.column1
    WHERE COALESCE(t1.column2,'') <> COALESCE(t2.column2,'')
        OR COALESCE(t1.column4,'') <> COALESCE(t2.column4,'')
```

Comment: It works!  I added distinct because it initially returned 5 times the amount of records that I had.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have another question about altering the criteria of this query.  Should I ask it here, or submit another post?

Comment: @user955289: What's the question?

Comment: I need a similar query that will return rows with differences, based on the data in the preceding field.  For example, in rows where column 1 is the same, column 4 may be null if the value in column 2 is different between the records.  The application is designed to ask questions based on the response, so if I ask what color the item is, and the answer is black, the next question has to be the same.  But if there are two answers, I can follow up with a question if the answer is black, but I don't have to ask that same question if the answer is silver.  I may have to explain in more detail.

Comment: @user955289 That sounds different enough to warrant a new post.